# Mobile friendly ASP.Net app to mobile app?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, xamarin, telerik

I have an **ASP.Net web application (web forms)** with `Telerik ajax` controls.

It is currently mobile-friendly, but I would like to put it into an app that a user could download from the app stores.

> Is there a quick and easy way to make this work using something like a
>   WebView or am I likely stuck writing a full native app? The
>   application​ is mostly data driven (lots of Telerik grids) and will
>   need an internet connection for most functions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create a native app that opens the web site inside a WebView.  That's fairly simple.  I've done as much in [the Video player app I wrote for my book](https://github.com/adrianhall/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/tree/master/Chapter7M).  However, that isn't in the spirit of mobile apps.  The point of putting it in the app store is generally to give your users an app that works like they expect on their phone.

If it is data driven, then expose the data via REST APIs and consume those APIs in a mobile app.  If you want offline sync (for resilience or performance), that's an additional consideration.  If you want mobile specific functionality like push notifications or authentication via touch id, for example, then those would also need a native app.

Short version - the simple "project my web app into a native app" is easy.  But it's unlikely to be satisfying to your users and won't allow you to extend your app with native features.

Comment: I want to get this out by fall so I might want to do the WebView route just to get something out there and then work on a native app to eventually replace that.

Comment: Another question. I've noticed some apps, for example my main banking app (bank of the west), look exactly the same between the app and the mobile site. Are they likely using a WebView? If not, how do they make it look so similar and clean? They can't be using Android SDK controls/components right? I've done some basic Android dev in Java with the Android SDK but all the apps have that same "Android" look and feel. Can the native libraries be used to make something that looks that nice?

Comment: @user2588873 If they're exactly the same, perhaps they're using HTML/CSS/JS in their web application to render the UI and using the same styling on their app and website. Possibly using something like Apache Cordova. To know for sure, you'd have to ask them. Technically with the native SDK they can make apps look however they want, so long as they put in the time to do it instead of using native UI controls.

Comment: Maybe Apache Cordova is what I really need, and not Xamarin?